# Set an object in a page's window object from a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want my Firefox extension to add an object to the content window of the browsed page. I want it to have the same effect as running:

```
top.myobj = {val : 3};
```

inside a script element in the page.

Any ideas?

I don't think there is a security risk here as I only add an object with a single integer property. Is there a simple way to get the content window object from within the extension code?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
var mainWindow = window
    .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
    .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebNavigation)
    .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDocShellTreeItem).rootTreeItem
    .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
    .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);

mainWindow.getBrowser().addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
                        youreventhandler, true);

function youreventhandler(event) {
    if (event.originalTarget instanceof HTMLDocument) {

        var doc = event.originalTarget;
        //doc = the document in the just loaded window

        var win = doc.defaultView;

        // if it's just a frame element, then return and wait for the   
        // main event to fire.
        if (win.frameElement)
            return;
        else {
            win.myobj = { val: 3};
            //your other code here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's probably way more code than needed.  If the add-on is already in the browser scope, like most add-ons, then getBrowser() can be called to get the browser object:
getBrowser().addEventListener(...)

Comment: Unfortunately the OP didn't provide much detail on the circumstances. In this case I figured too much was better than too little.

Comment: The problem is that someone landing on this page might just copy this "much" without understanding any of it. So please don't do this :)

Comment: @Nikolay, are you saying the answer is not useful? Down votes aren't intended to enforce your personal preference of answer length. Is the answer helpful or not?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [evalInSandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.utils.evalInSandbox) to execute the assignment in the context of `window.content` similarly to [this code](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.extensions/msg/3ba40f23b0bf2253):

```
// |content| refers to the current tab's |window| object
var s = new Components.utils.Sandbox(content);
s.window = content;
Components.utils.evalInSandbox(
   "window.wrappedJSObject.test = function() { } ", s)
```

BTW, re "I don't think there is a security risk here" - adding a property to an object may result in executing code (since JS has setters), so touching the content is always dangerous. The example above only touches insecure object (`content.wrappedJSObject`) in a sandbox without chrome permissions, so it's OK.

Comment: Note:The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.

Comment: Um, no. The Components object removal is content-only. It does not affect the code in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Does it need to be the window, or can it be the document itself? You can always use content.document reference the page itself. Or [window.content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.content) for the primary content window.

Comment: That doesn't let you set properties in the content window, though.