# How to set javascript variable in Firefox Add On created using the Add On SDK?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to set a javascript variable to identify that a Firefox extension is installed. The idea is to read this variable on the page.

After failing to implement this using the complicated approaches when using XUL add-ons ([Set an object in a page's window object from a Firefox extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438853/set-an-object-in-a-pages-window-object-from-a-firefox-extension)) and finding out about contentScripts in Firefox Add On SDK which looks suitable for the task, I am still having problems accessing javascript variables set in the contentScript on a page.

I have the following in my main.js (using the sample provided here https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html):

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScript: 'window.isInstalled=true;window.alert("Page matches ruleset");',
  contentScriptWhen: "ready"
});
```

However when I try to get the `window.isInstalled` variable in javascript on a page, it is undefined, despite the alert was shown.

**How to ensure that the value written by the content script will be available on a page?**

Comment: @nmaier you meant to say the other question is a duplicate of this one, since this one was asked and answered more than 6 months ago and yours is from yesterday, right?

Comment: Nope. I mean to close this question against the other one, which will become the canonical ("catch-all") question/answer for these types of questions. This does not mean your question is wrong or bad in my opionion; it is the opposite in fact, as the upvotes rightfully indicate. I actually considered just using your (this) question instead of posting a new one, but it is too limited in scope (only asking about variables) to become the canonical question. This is more of a house-keeping job and quite common in a lot of tags.

Comment: I really do not get what value it would bring if this is closed as a duplicate. This is the first Google hit for "how to set javascript variable firefox add on sdk" and many similar queries. Your "canonical" answer will never be found with similar keywords and will not provide any value.

Comment: The value is the obvious navigational pointer this will provide for users arriving at this question one way or another.

Comment: And what if someone decides to delete all duplicates in the future? This is not a duplicate, this is a question about a specific problem with a valuable answer. With this logic, you could close all C# questions as duplicates of a single "canonical" question with a single answer pointing to C# specification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `window` object in content scripts is generally an `XRayWrapper`, meaning that you'll get the original object back instead of whatever the website may have overwritten. That in turn also means, that the website won't see any modifications you make to the `window` object.

However, `unsafeWindow.isInstalled = ...` should work (although `.isInstalled` is very generic and may therefore clash with variables a website already uses).

See the [docs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/accessing-the-dom.html) regarding `XRayWrapper` and `unsafeWindow`.

Addressing the very valid concerns raised by @canuckistani:

Reading data from or executing functions of `unsafeWindow` is safe in the sense that it cannot directly lead to code execution in another (your content script) compartment. Spidermonkey's compartments will make sure of that. Everything else would be a security issue within either Spidermonkey or Gecko. (Please note that this refers to Spidermonkey only. IIRC it is the only engine to implement compartments or membranes or whatever you'd like to call it. Other engines might have other security properties).

But it is very true that you must never trust data coming from a website. `unsafeWindow` just have more ways to get you pwnd.
Always except code to throw, Denial-of-service you with an unexpected infinite loop or similar and never, ever explicitly or implicitly evaluate code in your context.

E.g. this is a security vulnerability, no matter if you use window or unsafeWindow:

```
for (var el of window.document.querySelectorAll("*[onclick]")) {
  el.addEventListener("click", el.getAttribute("onclick"));
  el.removeAttribute("onclick");
}
```

This would create anonymous functions (the event listeners) from website-controlled strings (`.getAttribute`) within *your* script context, no the context of a website.

This would be unsafe as well, but only when using `unsafeWindow` this time:

```
for (var el of unsafeWindow.document.querySelectorAll("p")) {
  el.addEventListener("click", 'alert("I am ' + el.clientHeight + 'px tall");');
  el.removeAttribute("onclick");
}
```

When using the `XRayWrapper` wrapped `window`, you can be sure that `document` is actually the document, `document.querySelectorAll` is actually a function spitting out some Elements and `el.clientHeight` is actually a numeric value.

Going through `unsafeWindow` all these assumptions may be incorrect. The website might have done something like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll = function() {
  return [{
    clientHeight: 'a pwnd content script"); doSomethingEvil(); alert("Now I own you! And I am certainly not 0'
  }];
};
```

While it is still safe in a privilege-escalation sense to execute `unsafeWindow.document.querySelectorAll`, as the overridden function would still run within the compartment (security context) of the website, the return value cannot be trusted at all.

Or the script might have done other things to break your stuff, not necessarily with malicious intent. E.g. your off-the-shell Denial-of-Service.

```
Object.defineProperty(document, "title", {
  get: function() { while(true); }
});
// or
Object.defineProperty(document, "title", {
  get: function() { throw new Error("get off my lawn!"); }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent so much time trying to make this work and the Addon SDK makes this very easy, given one knows what exactly to use. Indeed, isInstalled was just the first iteration, I will for sure use a very specific name for the variable. Thanks!

Comment: There *is* a security concern here, mainly that you should only ever *set* window.isInstalled, you should never trust any data that comes from unsafeWindow. But for your use case, this is fine.

Comment: @canuckistani I added a few bits about security to my answer.